# Sequelize associations between two tables

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am fairly new to this (using sequelize) and everything is new to me. The thing is that I can create and get users through my "users.model.js" but now I want to create a model called "data.model.js" to associate some data to a certain user.

So according to the sequelize docs, my associations should be the following:

```
Users.hasMany(Data)
Data.belongsTo(Users)
```

But when sequelize creates my tables, I don't have my foreign key in my data table.

I will share my code with you:

config file (config.js):

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const connection = new Sequelize('drglicemia', 'root', '', {
host: 'localhost',
dialect: 'mysql'
});

module.exports = connection;
```

data.model.js:

```
const sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../config/database');
const usersTable = require('./users.model')

let Data = db.define('tabeladados', {
    dta: { type: sequelize.DATEONLY },
    hora: { type: sequelize.DATE },
    indiceglicemia: { type: sequelize.STRING },
    insulina: { type: sequelize.STRING },
    medicacao: { type: sequelize.STRING },
}, {
    timeStamps: false, tableName: 'tabeladados'
});

//associates the dataTable table with the users
Data.associate = () => {
    Data.belongsTo(usersTable)
}


module.exports = Data;
```

users.model.js:

```
const sequelize = require('sequelize');
const promise = require('bluebird')
const bcrypt = promise.promisifyAll(require('bcrypt'))
const db = require('../config/database');
const dataTable = require('./data.model')

let Users = db.define('utilizadores', {
    username: { type: sequelize.STRING },
    email: { type: sequelize.STRING },
    password: { type: sequelize.STRING },
}, {
    timeStamps: false, tableName: 'utilizadores',
});


//encrypts the password before submiting to the database
Users.beforeCreate((user, options) => {

    return bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10)
        .then(hash => {
            user.password = hash;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            throw new Error();
        });
});

//validates the password submited by the user with the one encrypted in the database
Users.prototype.validPassword = async (password) => {
    return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
}

//associates the users table with the dataTable
Users.associate = () => {
    Users.hasMany(dataTable)
}

module.exports = Users;
```

I believe that when I am trying to associate my tables I am doing something wrong, because I feel that I am doing it the wrong way.

I don't know but everything works besides this.

But it's like what I said in the beginning, I am new to sequelize xD

Comment: hey Francisco, how are these models be used? I mean, are you going to access the data from users, like `user.data` or users from data, like `data.user`?

Comment: @germanio Hi, oh boy, good question xD

ahhh, so I am going to access the data from the users :D

Comment: Ok cool, so you are going to get an array of data entries for each user?

Comment: @germanio yes! exactly :D

Comment: Perfect, I would suggest you take a look at this: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#one-to-many-relationships
It describes how to do the association in the models, to allow sequelize to create the right tables

Comment: oh wait, it seems you already come from there hehe
check this part: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#customizing-the-foreign-key
this is a way to let sequelize know how to map the two tables

Comment: I tried it but even if I delete my tables I can't get my foreign key generated by sequelize :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is **circular reference**. `user.model.js` requires `data.model.js`, and `data.model.js` requires `user.model.js`.

You need to create an `index.js` file. Require and make the associations for all models here, then re-export them. E.g.

`./models/index.js`:

```js
const User = require('./user.model.js');
const Data = require('./data.model.js');

User.hasMany(Data);
Data.belongsTo(User);

module.exports = {User, Data}
```

`service.js` or `controller.js`:

```js
const models = require('./models/index.js');
// use models
await models.User.findAll();
```

Remove below codes in your model file:

```
// Remove from user.model.js file
Users.associate = () => {
    Users.hasMany(dataTable)
}
// Remove from data.model.js file
Data.associate = () => {
    Data.belongsTo(usersTable)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! For your answer!

But now I am confused beacuse should I import the index.js to my models like this?

require('../models/index')

But if I do this it says that hasMany is not a function :(

(I'm sorry but I am really a vegetable)

Comment: @FranciscoMendes You shouldn't import `index.js` to your models' file. It will also cause the circular reference issue. The `index.js` is some kind of orchestration for your models, it should be imported and consumed by your service or controller.

Comment: Oh I get it now. But it there a way to sequelize to build the data table when it connects to the database?(and makes the associations) Because the only table that gets built is the users table.

Comment: @FranciscoMendes Check this example: https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/tree/master/models, this is another way to make the associations. It put the model definition in a Factory function, and use `Model.associate = (models) => {...}` to make the associations for models. It avoids the circular reference issue. I am not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: With your example both tables are created but I don't know why, I don't have the foreign key, even if I name it "uid" or if I set it to allowNull: false.  I don't know why this is persisting. But thank you so much for spending your time solving my problem, I mean it :D