# How i do a relation betwwen to tables in sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

```
export const users = db.define('users', {
    id: {
        type: sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    username: {
        type: sequelize.STRING
    },
    password: {
        type: sequelize.STRING
    },
    creationtime: {
        type: sequelize.DATE
    },
    lastconnection: {
        type: sequelize.DATE
    },
    email:{
        type:sequelize.STRING
    }

});


export const emailToken = db.define('emailtoken',{
    id:{
        type:sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement:true,
        primaryKey:true
    },
    userid:{
        type:sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    emailToken:{
        type:sequelize.STRING
    }
})
```

how i made a relation from userid in emailToken to id in users
i tried to make user.hasOne(emailToken) but the sequelize still giving errors about the table i did

[this is what i did in php myadmin to crate the association](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7U86u.png)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There is already a post that can help you friend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61257195/sequelize-associations-between-two-tables